# How do I create a bar between navigation bar and table header?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In NYTimes iPhone application, one bar exist in between table header and navigation bar on the top news screen.

what bar is that? or it's just a label in between navigation bar and table header?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to get some help if you provide a screenshot of what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's probably just a pair of labels with their background color set to gray and their text color to white. They might actually be implementing it in some other fashion (I haven't seen their code), but certainly that's the easiest way to do it.